# Importing .css and cdn's in the index.html file when using vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

Hello and hope all are safe,
I have a browser reset.css file in /src/assets/css that will be used site wide in my vue project. So I figured would just import it into the /public/index.html via a  . However this does not work and I see an error in the console - "The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/src/assets/css/styles.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”." I am using

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

in the index.html file. I am using vue-cli3 and was wondering what is the accepted way of applying site wide css rule's and also the proper way of importing CDN link's? I dont see this scenerio addressed in vue-cli documentation. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> href="../src/assets/css/styles.css"

We don't do that here. It's not pratical. `/public/index.html` is a template that will be processed with html-webpack-plugin(to pack your vue App). During build, asset links will be injected automatically

go to your `App.vue` file under  tag, add the import line before `export default`

```
</template>
<script>
import '@/assets/css/styles.css';
.
.
.
```

if u need scoped styling in components

just add `src=[import path above]` in `<style scoped>`

And Vue docs is very well-written. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html

Comment: Thanks. That did it. So basically dont touch the index.html file and do all your css imports via the html-webpack-plugin? I did google fonts thru link in index.html. is that correct?